# Extreme value theory for count data

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data, extreme-value

I am aware of extreme value theory for continuous distributions. I need to fit an extreme value distribution to the maximum observation of number of events on a day, per month. This seems to be the block maxima problem, which is approximated by the GEV family of distributions for continuous distributions.  How do I do this for count data?

As a secondary question, let's assume the basic count process is ~ Poisson. Then does this lead to a different answer to the original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any recent visitors, there's been new developments in this area by Hitz, Davis and Samorodnitsky (arXiv:1707.05033). Taking a peaks-over-threshold approach instead of block maxima, the Discrete Generalised Pareto Distribution is derived as the $\operatorname{floor}$ of a GPD, and discrete Maximum Domains of Attraction (DMDA) are introduced by relating them to the classical MDAs. The whole thing is linked to, but different from, [Zipf's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).

In terms of the paper's terminology, the Poisson distribution is in the DMDA of a Gumbel distribution $(\xi = 0)$, as are the Negative Binomial and Geometric distributions.

Comment: This looks more like a comment. Can you please make it more complete, by a short summary of what is in that paper?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I've edited the question, is that better?

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know a definitive answer for your primary question. Although I found the following two references:

[Anderson, C. W., “Extreme value theory for a class of discrete distributions with applications to some stochastic processes”, Journal of Applied Probability, vol 7, 1970, pp. 99–113.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3212152)

[Anderson, C. W., “Local limit theorems for the maxima of discrete random variables”,
Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, vol 88, 1980, pp. 161–
165.](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=DC999372089497C149031565F99F7683.journals?fromPage=online&aid=2082124)

For your secondary question, the CDF of the Poisson is $\frac{\Gamma(\lfloor k+1\rfloor,\lambda)}{\lfloor k\rfloor!}$ so $P(\max\limits_N X_n \leq M) = (\frac{\Gamma(\lfloor k+1\rfloor,\lambda)}{\lfloor k\rfloor!})^N$. Apply the difference operator (lag1) and you get the PMF of the max.

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson does not fall within the MDA of any EV distribution (not possible to find shifting and scaling sequences that provide a non-degenerate limit).  Consequence of a theorem in Leadbetter, Lindgren and Rootzen (1983).